# Microsoft 70339 certification exam

Tags: certification, exam

I wanted to know if Managing Microsoft SharePoint 2016 (70-339) comes under MCP or not .

Currently i am planning for this exam and i am not able to figure out under which category currently this exam lies.

I do have a MCP exam voucher but that only include certification exams under MCP .So is this exam included inside this MCP ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm aiming to do this when I have a chance, the 339: Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016 is one of the elective exams specified within the [MCSE: Productivity](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcse-productivity-certification.aspx) certification.

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this one Is included inside the MCSE Productivity exam. You can use your voucher to register for this exam. Also do buy the practise test from mind hub if you want additional practise but don't go for dumps.